# Canonical commutation relations in Light-cone gauge

Tags: string-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, quantization, constrained-dynamics

It seems that when trying to identify the physical degrees of freedom for the string some authors$^1$ use:
$$ q^-=\frac{1}{\ell}\int_0^{\ell} X^-(\tau,\sigma)d\sigma$$

Then, the commutation relation is
$$[q-,p^+]=-i$$

Other authors$^2$ choose the constant part of $X^-=x_0^- + f(\tau,\sigma)$
so the commutation relation is
$$[x_0^- ,p^+]=-i$$

You can think that this is just a free choice, however everybody uses the same hamiltonian
$$H=2\alpha' p^+p^-$$ Of course, $p^-$ is an integral but my point is that the same $H$ cannot work for both cases.

Because in the second case the equation of motion for $x_0^-$ leads to $$\dot{x_0^-} =0$$
which is expected($x_0^-$ is constant as pointed out in $^2$).

But in the first case it would be $q^-=$constant which is wrong, or there must be something I am missing here.

In short, my questions are:

Why this is happening?

Why some people use $[q-,p^+]=-i$ and others use $[x_0^- ,p^+]=-i$?

RELATION BETWEEN $q^-$ and $x^-_0$

I am going to use eq. (12.98) in Zwiebach's book.
$$ X^-(\tau,\sigma)=x^- _0 +\sqrt{2\alpha'}\alpha^-_0 \tau + oscillators$$
Since the oscillators will not contribute anything, integration leads
$$ q^-=\frac{1}{\ell}\int_0^{\ell} X^-(\tau,\sigma)d\sigma=x^- _0 +\sqrt{2\alpha'}\alpha^-_0 \ \tau$$

---

$^1$ Sundermeyer; Constrained Dynamics, Lecture Notes in Physics; page 220; also see this [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/184742/reduction-of-nambu-goto-action-to-true-degrees-of-freedom/185297?s=1%7C0.1447#185297).

also see Ralph Blumenhagen, Dieter Lust and Stefan Theisen; Basic Concepts of String Theory; pages 24 and 44.

$^2$ Zwiebach; A first course in String Theory, 2nd edition; 2009; page 238

Comment: To me, the way you've defined $q^-$, you're just going to get $x_0^-$ back. The oscillators won't contribute anything. How do you get your equations of motion?

Comment: $i\dot{E}=[E,H]$ $E=q^-$ or $E=x_0^-$

Comment: If you want a relation between them, it would be $q^-=x_0^- +constant \tau$. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Write down the expression for $X^-$ and explicitly integrate it. See what you get.

Comment: @leastaction I saw what I got. Integration has been added to the question. what else? what is the idea?

Answer (score 1):

Comments to the question (v3):

1. The $X^-$ coordinate has (a part from a zero mode) been integrated out in the light-cone (LC) formalism. The above mentioned LC Hamiltonian cannot fully address questions about the $X^-$ coordinate.
2. To get the well-known expansion of $X^-$ as a sum of zero and oscillator modes including the sought-for $\alpha^-_0$ mode term, one has to go back to the full string formulation prior to the LC reduction, cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/185297/2451). By doing this, one may show that the $\alpha^-_0$ mode term indeed appears in the expansion of $X^-$ as it should.