# Importance and Origin of level matching condition

Tags: string-theory

I want to know the origin of level-matching condition of string theory.

And want to know why many string theory textbook mention that this condition is crucial.

Is this level matching condition always right? ( Does all string theory satisfy the level matching condition ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments to the question (v1):

1. The [level matching condition](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=level+matching+condition) (LMC) for closed strings arises from the reparametrization invariance $\sigma\to \sigma +\sigma_0$ under a constant shift.
2. Open strings do not have this reparametrization symmetry under a constant shift because of the two endpoints, nor do they have the LMC.
3. To more concretely see how the LMC arises in the Hamiltonian formulation of the closed [Nambo-Goto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nambu%E2%80%93Goto_action) string, see e.g. eq. (22) in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/185297/2451).

Comment: Correction to the answer (v2): _Nambo_ should be _Nambu._