# Nambu-Goto action and zweibein

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, string-theory, coordinate-systems, gauge-theory

Consider the Nambu-Goto action
\begin{equation}
S=\int d\sigma d\tau \sqrt{(\partial_\sigma X^\mu \partial_\tau X_\mu)^2-(\partial_\sigma X^\mu\partial_\sigma X_\mu)(\partial_\tau X^\mu\partial_\tau X_\mu)}.
\end{equation}
We have that $\partial_\tau X^\mu$ and $\partial_\sigma X^\mu$ are element of the tangent space to the string. Alternatively, $S$ can be written in terms of the induced metric
\begin{equation}
S=\int d\sigma d\tau \sqrt{-\text{det}{g}}.
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
g=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\partial_\tau X^\mu\partial_\tau X_\mu & \partial_\sigma X^\mu \partial_\tau X_\mu \\
\partial_\sigma X^\mu \partial_\tau X_\mu & \partial_\sigma X^\mu\partial_\sigma X_\mu 
\end{array}\right].
\end{equation}
Let us now work in the static gauge. We have seen in class that there is a specific reference frame in which the calculations are easier to perform, that is one constrained by, calling the new reference frame $(\sigma',\tau')$,
\begin{align}
\partial_{\sigma'} \vec{X}^\mu \partial_{\tau'} \vec{X}_\mu =0 \\
\partial_{\tau'} \vec{X}^\mu\partial_{\tau'} \vec{X}_\mu + \partial_{\sigma'} \vec{X}^\mu\partial_{\sigma'} \vec{X}_\mu=1. 
\end{align}
These conditions can be obtained by requiring that the old equation of motion for the Nambu-Goto action take the form of a wave equation, $\partial_\tau^2 X^\mu-\partial_\sigma^2 X^\mu=0$. The first thing to note is that under the first constraint on the chosen parametrization the induced metric is diagonal, that is
\begin{equation}
g=\text{diag}(\partial_{\tau'} X^\mu\partial_{\tau'} X_\mu, \partial_{\sigma'} X^\mu\partial_{\sigma'} X_\mu)=\text{diag}(\partial_{\tau'} X^\mu\partial_{\tau'} X_\mu, \partial_{\sigma'} \vec{X}^\mu\partial_{\sigma'} \vec{X}_\mu).
\end{equation}
where the second equality was obtained by using that the zeroth component of $X$, in the static gauge, is independent of $\sigma$.
Furthermore, according to the second condition:
\begin{equation}
\partial_{\sigma'} \vec{X}^\mu\partial_{\sigma'} \vec{X}_\mu=1-\partial_{\tau'} \vec{X}^\mu\partial_{\tau'} \vec{X}_\mu=-\partial_{\tau'} X^\mu\partial_{\tau'} X_\mu. 
\end{equation}
It follows that in this frame
\begin{equation}
g=-\partial_{\tau'} X^\mu\partial_{\tau'} X_\mu \text{diag}(-1,1).
\end{equation}
My first question is, assuming everything I wrote is correct:

- Is it true that, up to rescaling of $\tau$, the new frame corresponds to the zweibein frame of the string? That is, if we further rescaled $\tau$, we would find $g=\text{diag}(-1,1)$, which seems to me the defining property of the orthonormal frame.

My second question is

- What does the action look like in this specific frame? I would expect it to be an action reproducing immediately the wave equation $\partial_\tau^2 X^\mu-\partial_\sigma^2 X^\mu=0$.
- At the same time, consider a frame in which $g=\text{diag}(-1,1)$. Then I would expect the action to be constant! So what would the equations of motion be?

I'm aware these questions most likely come from confusing objects and transformations, but I cannot wrap my head around them.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/184742/2451