Light-cone gauge
I'm trying to understand the existence of the light-cone gauge for the closed bosonic string in a more mathematical precise language.
Namely, when looking for critical points of Polyakov action, we can

Choose local coordinates (in case of cylinder, these are called $(\sigma,\tau)$, more generally let's call them $(\sigma_1 , \sigma_2$))

Write the world sheet metric $h = \exp(2f)\eta$ over conceivable a new, possibly smaller coordinate patch (abusing notation, I think physics texts are OK if we just call the restricted coordinates of the new patch $(\sigma_1,\sigma_2)$ again)

Ignore the exponential prefactor by Weyl invariance.


At this point, the E.o.M are free wave equations for each coordinate of the string in addition to the two Virasoro constraints.

Define "light-cone" coordinates $\sigma^{\pm} = \sigma_1 \pm \sigma_2$. At this point, one solves easily the wave equations by Fourier expansions and can see the $M^2 = \sum (\mathrm{Fourier \ modes})$ formula.

Yet somehow physics textbooks say there is still gauge redundancy remaining on the worldsheet.
With a mathematical background in differential geometry, I am having trouble understanding what physics texts are expressing here. We have a specific local chart on the world sheet and spacetime too. Why is there still redundancy? And how do we know the light-cone gauge exists?

Essentially a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/184742/2451

So let me see if I got this right: we fix light cone coordinates in the target, and then the claim is that there exist world sheet coordinates $(\sigma, \tau)$ such that $X^+ (\sigma,\tau) \propto \tau$. From what I've seen, it is further claimed that in this coordinates, the metric is still conformally flat. How can we prove any of this?
